# How to run GStreamer (Aravissrc & AWS Kinesis Video Stream) on boot

Tags: linux, gstreamer

This might be something simple for some folks but for newbie like myself, I couldn’t figure it out and wanted to ask for some help.

I am looking to run this command on boot -

```
gst-launch-1.0 aravissrc ! video/x-raw, format=RGB,width=640,height=480 ! videoconvert! video/x-raw,format=YUY2 ! videoconvert ! x264enc bframes=0 key-int-max=45 bitrate=512 tune=zerolatency ! h264parse ! video/x-h264,stream-format=avc,alignment=au,profile=baseline ! kvssink stream-name=" YOUR_STREAM_NAME" storage-size=512 access-key="YOUR_AWS_ID" secret-key="YOUR_AWS_SECRET_KEY: aws-region=" YOUR_AWS_REGION"
```

I added this command inside of a shell script and was trying to run the script using `/etc/rc.local` but it hasn’t been working. I tried running the script itself, but I was getting

> WARNING: erroneous pipeline: no element “aravissrc”

I added export environment variables, but still no luck. When I run that command on terminal, it works without any issue. Any thoughts on what I am missing?

Would appreciate any feedback!

Thanks,

Jae

Answer (score 0):

First thing you can do is check if the environment variables do get set automatically when you boot. You can do this by running `printenv`

One more thing is, there is a possibility you might have to run the command from the gst directory directly. When you ran the command on terminal, which directory did you run it from? Try changing directory in the script and see if it helps.

Comment: thanks for the pointer. Wanted to make sure I understood your comment correctly. When you say "check if the env variables do get set automatically on boot. You can do this by running `printenv`" Should I check it within the script or right after it was booted?

Comment: I actually made sure I checked from anywhere. The command I run on terminal - I can run it from any directory.